# Matching cards exercise with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm playing around with a matching cards exercise in jquery. When the card classes are matched, I'd like the border to turn red. However, my code block is not running. Any suggestions?

```
if ($(".selected").length == 2) {
      numberOfMoves++
      var card1 = $(".selected:eq(0)").attr("class");
      var card2 = $(".selected:eq(1)").attr("class");

      if(card1 == card2) {
       $(".selected").addClass("matched").removeClass("selected");
        }
      }
```

http://codepen.io/ElaineM/pen/uhdzC

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change your CSS to:

```
.queen.matched {
  background: purple;
  border: 20px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I can't believe I missed that.